# How to add button to pivot header

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to add a button to the pivot header so that it is shown in-line with pivot item titles, but doesn't update the content shown but just launches an event instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimenting, I discovered how to do this. First place a button inside a PivotItem's header. Set it up to route tap events as well as click events.

```
<PivotItem>
            <PivotItem.Header>
                <Button
                    x:Name="MyButton"
                    Tapped="PivotItem_Tapped"
                    Click="MyButton_Click">MyButton</Button>
            </PivotItem.Header>
</PivotItem>
```

Then inside the handler for the tap, consume the tap event. Clicking on the button won't update the pivot's content now:

```
private void MyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //do whatever you need.
        }

 private void PivotItem_Tapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```